# Implementing Target Tracking on a boat

Tags: ros, stereo, tracking, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to design and implement a target tracking system on a boat and I am searching to find a suitable sensor to do this. As you know we can not use Kinect outdoors. another option is stereo camera but i am not sure if it works properly or what is the range of detection of target with stereo camera. I would appreciate any help in finding a good approach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232087/implementing-target-tracking-on-a-boat/) by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The (usable) depth range of a stereo camera is directly related to the baseline, resolution and lenses employed. [Here](http://nerian.com/support/resources/calculator/) is a online calculator that could be helpful for computing/playing around with different parameters.

Using a Kinect (v1) outdoors is not a good idea, but it seems like Kinect V2 and Intel R200 provide some robustness to outdoor lighting conditions.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on 2016-04-21**:
Thank you. Based on my search it seems that kinect V2 is not good in daylight but it has acceptable results in cloudy and shadow cases.
It seems that Stereo is the best choice. I will state the practical tests results right here under this question.